# How to add a new view to django-oscar

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-urls, django-oscar

I don't think I fully grasp the django-oscar documentation. I am trying to add a new view, a home view at `/` of the site. But whatever I seem to do it keeps going to `/catalogue/` when I want to access `/` instead.

it says I should do the following:

```
from oscar.apps.offer.apps import OfferConfig as CoreOfferConfig
from .views import IndexView
from django.conf.urls import url


class OfferConfig(CoreOfferConfig):
    def ready(self):
        super().ready()
        self.index_view = IndexView

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        urls += [
            url(r'^$', self.index_view.as_view(), name='index'),
        ]
        return self.post_process_urls(urls)
```

and this is in `myproject/myapp/offer/apps.py`. `myapp` was created following the django-oscar tutorial which involved running the command `./manage.py oscar_fork_app order myapp`.

general breakdown of the folder:

```
myproject:
    - myproject
        - settings.py
        ...
    - static
    - myapp
        - order
        - offer
            - apps.py
        - __init.py
    - templates
    manage.py
```

my urls.py in `myproject` looks as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.apps import apps

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the view I am trying to add is very very basic at the moment:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        products = ['empy', 'for', 'now']
        context.update({
            'products': products,
        })
        return context
```

what am I doing wrong?

I am using `django-oscar 2.0.4`,`django 2.2.12`, `python 3.7.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just the index view you want to override, then it may be easier just to insert a URL pattern in from of Oscar's patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('', IndexView.as_view()),
    url(r'^', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]
```

This will cause your `IndexView` to match ahead of Oscar's.

Alternatively, you need to override the `catalogue` app [where the home page view is defined](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/apps.py#L29). In your question you have forked the `offer` app, which doesn't contain that view and hence you changes have no effect. If you take that approach then the correct way to override the view is to set `self.catalogue_view` in the `ready()` method of the app, rather than adding a new URL pattern:

```
class CatalogueConfig(CoreCatalogueConfig):
    def ready(self):
        super().ready()
        # This is all - you don't need to mess with the URLs.
        self.catalogue_view = IndexView
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not understand the forking by the looks of it. I was blindly following the documentation on that part. This solved my issue and gave me a better understanding. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

index is in :
oscar/apps/catalogue/apps.py

you have to fork catalogue